# How to use elements that I selected from a table in database and compare with another table as I am looping through each row

Tags: php, sql, database

I am looping through the rows with fetch_assoc in table City. Then as I am looping through the rows I want to compare the values that each row has with the values of table Subscriber. I don't want to loop through each row for the Subscriber table,I just want to compare the values that it has on City columns.

I don't want to loop through each row for the Subscriber table,I just want to compare the values that it has on City columns.

This is my code:

```
$query = "SELECT Location1,Location2,Location3,Location4,Location5,Location6,Location7,Location8 FROM City";

if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {


$Location1 =  $row['Location1'];
$Location2 =  $row['Location2'];
$Location3 =  $row['Location3'];
$Location4 =  $row['Location4'];
$Location5 =  $row['Location5'];
$Location6 =  $row['Location6'];
$Location7 =  $row['Location7'];
$Location8 =  $row['Location8'];






$sql = mysql_query('SELECT City, Email FROM Subscriber');
```

I expect to compare if the column City of subscriber is equal to any of the locations of City.

Comment: option a) add a `WHERE` clause to your second query. option b) add a `JOIN` clause to your first query. you can read up on both in the mysql manual. side note: *don't* use `mysql_`-functions, they are deprecated for years now and in php7, completely removed.

Comment: Thank you for the options:) So can I say for example SELECT City FROM Subscriber WHERE City = $row['Location1'] OR $row['Location2'] OR $row['Location3'] for example? Also if that is true I would like to send an email to the subscriber that the city is equal to any of the locations. Thank you

Comment: What willbe the action of the comparison ? Do you want to display the city names which are common ? If yes then use this code : select city from Subscriber where city in (SELECT Location1, Location2, Location3, Location4, Location5, Location6, Location7, Location8 FROM City) .